# How can I specify an external dependency in JBoss 5

Tags: jboss, jar, dependencies, classpath, external

OK so I have a couple of jars that I need for my JBoss application to run.  Under normal circumstances, I would just copy these jars into my apps WEB-INF/lib folder and rock on.

*However*, these jars are part of a third party library and they have dependencies on a whole host of .dlls and other stuff in the directory where they live.  So I can't just copy the jars because the copies won't work because they don't have all of the stuff surrounding them like the originals do.

What I want to do, then, is tell JBoss where to look to find these jars, which will be in C:/Program Files/SomeDirectory/Common.  I tried just adding these jars to my ClassPath, but that doesn't work because JBoss's classloader won't use that for user apps (right?).

Is there a way I can tell JBoss's Class loader "Hey, look over here! These are the jars you want!"?

Comment: Can't you just put all the necessary files into `${JBOSS_HOME}/server/default/lib`?